# SQLite Foreign Key Relationship with Godot

Tags: sqlite, godot

This is the only way that I found to get the information from a `foreign_key` relationship. Is there a better way?

```
db.query("SELECT owner FROM dog_names;")
print(db.query_result)
print(db.query_result[0])
var o = db.query_result[0]["owner"]
print(o)
var o_str = "SELECT name FROM owners WHERE id = {int};"
var o_form = o_str.format({"int": o})
db.query(o_form)
print(db.query_result)
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. There is a wait period if I recall correctly.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I had never heard of JOIN before. I had to tweak your answer a hair, but couldn't have gotten to my answer without yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query_str = "SELECT name FROM owners JOIN dogs ON owners.id = dogs.id;"
db.query(query_str)
print(db.query_result)
```

The below guide is from https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/joins.php

```
SELECT columns
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column = table2.column;
```